# Remove decimals of Floats in Python

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point

New to Python.couldn't figure out how to remove the decimal digits from float. 
x=[1.2,1.5,2.4]
how to get the following output
[1. 1. 2.]

thanks.

Comment: `import math; list(map(math.floor, x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `math.trunc`. If you still want floats you have to convert them again

```
 import math
 list(map(lambda x: float(math.trunc(x)), [1.2, 1.5, 2.4]))
```